# Bitlocker unlocking started in Another System. Not completed. Now that system is not accessible

Tags: bitlocker

I have started unlocking Bitlocker in a system but due to huge data in my 1TB external HDD, unlocking didn't completed in available time. I had to leave that system and now that particular system is not accessible. When try to open and unlock the drive in another system it show error message. Now unable to open the drive and also unable to continue unlocking the drive..I have pw and recovery key both.

Comment: Is there any error on non-completion?  Otherwise I am not sure how you will access the data.

Comment: Would you mind to add the exact error message to your question?